# FancyBox image not full height. I want to remove top space & thumb list space below image

Tags: fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox 2. It's beauty, but I need gallery auto size show maximum height by browser:

Screenshot: http://nimb.ws/9sqJ6m

This's HTML (i used 1600x900 screen, viewport 1600x785)

```
<div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: visible; width: 690px; height: 690px;"><img class="fancybox-image" src="http://redboxstudio.vn/wp-content/fancygallery/1/1/IPG_Streetview-Custom.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

This file: http://redboxstudio.vn/wp-content/plugins/radykal-fancy-gallery/js/jquery.fancygallery.min.js?ver=2.3.3

```
        getViewport: function() {
        var a = b.current && b.current.locked || !1,
            d = {
                x: n.scrollLeft(),
                y: n.scrollTop()
            };
        a ? (d.w = a[0].clientWidth, d.h = a[0].clientHeight) : (d.w = s && r.innerWidth ? r.innerWidth : n.width(), d.h = innerHeight ? r.innerHeight : n.height());
        return d
    },
```

Comment: Add your codes in your question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All!
I had to solve the problem
Find:

```
            y = l(x[1] + x[3]),
            r = l(x[0] + x[2]),
```

Replace by (to full height with viewport):

```
            y = l(x[1] + x[3]),
            r = l(x[3]),
```

Find

```
                c = {
                position: "absolute",
                top: c[0],
                left: c[3]
            };
```

Replace (to change top space):

```
                c = {
                position: "absolute",
                top: c[3],
                left: c[3]
            };
```